# How speed up processing list of elements in R?

Tags: r, list, performance

Let see the following case.

There is a list of tags that should be processed.
Here is I used "for" loop and it works for small lists. 
But for lists with a million elements it's too long.
How to speed such kind of processing.

```
# 1. List of 'original' tags
list_tags_original <- c(",tag1, tag2,, tag3", "tag3, tag4,", "tag5")

# 2. List of 'adjusted' tags
list_tags_adjusted <- c()

# 3. Process each 'original' tags
for(i in 1:length(list_tags_original)) {

  # 3.1. List of selected tags
  list_tags_selected <- list_tags_original[i]

  # 3.2. Split on separate tags
  list_tags_selected <- trimws(unlist(str_split(list_tags_selected, ",")))

  # 3.3. Drop 'missing' tags
  list_tags_selected <- list_tags_selected[list_tags_selected != ""]

  # 3.4. Merge back into the string
  list_tags_selected <- paste0(list_tags_selected, collapse = ",")

  # 3.5. Add to list of 'adjusted' tags
  list_tags_adjusted <- c(list_tags_adjusted, list_tags_selected)

} # for

# 4. Result
list_tags_adjusted
#[1] "tag1,tag2,tag3" "tag3,tag4"      "tag5"
```

Comment: For vectorized operations the `lapply` function is generally much faster than `for` loops

Comment: I tried it as well and parallel "foreach". No results

Comment: Does no results mean that you didn't get it to work, or it was not any faster?

Comment: it was not faster at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will defintely be faster than `for` loop :

```
sapply(strsplit(list_tags_original, ',\\s*'), function(x) toString(x[x!='']))
#[1] "tag1, tag2, tag3" "tag3, tag4"       "tag5"
```

The things wrong in `for` loop are :

1) `str_split` `trimws` functions which are vectorized but you are using it for only one element in `for` loop.

2) Never grow your objects in `for` loop, `list_tags_adjusted` is growing by size of 1 in each iteration.

Comment: Thanks Ronak! It mainly what I need. One issue left - using "trimws" to drop spaces for each tag when it splitted

Comment: Added to include whitespace in `strsplit`.

Comment: It's extremely cool, Ronak! Thanks a lot. Let me accept it as an answer, please.

Comment: @Ronal I checked code when "list_tags_adjusted = list_tags_original" on the init stage, and then updated it by "list_tags_adjusted[i] = list_tags_selected". So, by using preallocate memory. It also works much more faster. Thank you for the advice to not grow objects inside "for" loop!

Comment: Yes, `for` loops are not particularly slower. Most of the times, it is the code written inside it which makes it slower.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe using `gsub` can be faster?

```
gsub(",+", ",", gsub(" +|^,+|,+$", "", list_tags_original))
#[1] "tag1,tag2,tag3" "tag3,tag4"      "tag5"
```